# Adding a new accomplishment without sounding pretentious

Tags: interpretation

In an informal interview where the host and the audience already know about the new accomplishment, the interviewee brags like in the following sentences.

> Can you imagine! I am a journalist, a photographer and a traveler, but
>   I think I'll have to add to the list "author of a children's book that
>   has sold well."

Take into account that it's being said in a playful and lighthearted way, so everybody knows that she is trying to be funny.

How can those sentences be put in a way that english native speakers that don't see the interviewee, but that are reading the interview transcription, don't see the interviewee as pretentious or pompous?

Comment: Tone, gestures, and facial expressions are going to be more important than the actual wording.

Comment: @J.R. I edited the question to add some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you imagine!

and phrases like this are a red flag for bragging, especially since you are presenting a list of your experiences

If the point of saying this is to add on the book, then

> *Not only* am I a journalist, a photographer and a traveler, but I've also written a children's book that has sold well.

or if relevance of your other experiences is the point, then

> I am a journalist, a photographer and a traveler, and *have been able to combine these* into writing a children's book that has sold well.

may be softer ways of explaining the relevance of your experiences by tying them all together.

Of course intonation and how you present yourself will always effect how your message is received.

Comment: The third quotation is the one I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: That assumes the book uses to being a photographer and a traveler in the story, being a journalist (writer) is obvious.

Comment: I'd say the opener *Can you imagine!* strongly implies *humility*, not *bragging*. Braggarts tend to think any plaudits they get are no more than expected, given their obvious prowess. Only humble people say *Gosh! Imagine **me** getting an OBE!* Given that, as soon as we hear ***Not only** am I...* in OP's context we know that it's meant to be understood as facetious/self-deprecating.

Comment: I would say "Can you imagine!" is a challenge to the listener whereas "I never would have imagined getting an OBE.", "Imagine me getting an OBE." are a more introspective statements, of course "Imagine little 'ol me getting an OBE" may go either way depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

> I am the author of a successful children's book

should be sufficiently informative yet humble.

"Successful" is one of those significant-yet-meaningless terms that gives no other information other than you, personally, think the book is a success.  If your listeners are curious, they will ask questions.  Otherwise, it sounds mildly impressive, but more like description than braggadocio.